# исключение обратной взаимосвязи в Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Есть модель пользователя:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=100)
    patronymic = models.CharField('Отчество', max_length=100)
```

Есть модель ресурсов:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Название', max_length=30)
    slug =  models.SlugField('Slug', max_length=30, unique=True)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name='resource')
```

Требуется написать функцию во views, которая будет делать выборку всех пользователей, у которых еще нет ресурса:

```
def res_creater(request):
    person_list = Person.objects.filter(status='A').exclude()
    return person_list
```

Знаю, что написал **related_name='resource'**, но не могу понять как вывести обратную связь. В шаблоне спокойно использую data.persons.all для вывода всех пользователей, имеющих ресурсы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что писать в **exclude()** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, который я использовал в своём проекте, общепринятая практика.

```
# Выберет всех Person, у которых resource отсутствует.
person_list = Person.objects.filter(resource__isnull=True)
```

> Требуется написать функцию во views, которая будет делать выборку всех полььзователей, у которых еще нет ресурса

Проверено.

Comment: Прошу прощения, опечатка.Спасибо - Ваш вариант подходит! Правда есть один вопрос, а что если ресурсов много и у пользователя есть скажем ресурс "ВК", но нет ресурса "ОК". В таком случае в "ОК" он не выведет пользователей у которых есть "ОК".

Comment: В таком случае сделайте проверку для ресурса и два фильтра.

Comment: Понял. Ещё раз спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что это самый лучший вариант, но вашу проблему скорее всего решит

```
person_list = Person.objects.exclude(id__in=Resource.objects.values_list('persons__id', flat=True))
```

Comment: не работает. выводит пустой список. для примера я 1 пользователя сделал с ресурсом. на нем и проверяю.

Answer (score -1):

Немного разобравшись, пришел к такому коду:

```
def res_creater(request, slug):
    i = Resourсe.objects.get(slug=slug)
    person_list = Person.objects.filter(status='A').exclude(resource__id=i.id)
    return person_list
```

Возможно есть еще вариант решения?

Comment: а как этот код решает вашу проблему о выборке пользователей у которых нет ресурса?

Comment: если я правильно разобрался (возможно и не совсем), делаю запрос на текущий ресурс с которым работаю. Затем делаю фильтрацию по активным пользователям и исключаю из них тех, которые завязаны с текущим ресурсом (его id). Я не утверждаю, что он истинно правильный, но он выводит то, что мне нужно, а именно - пользователей, которые не имеют текущего ресурса